# VBA copying visible cells only issues

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to execute my code but it gives me

> Error 1004

Although I have used similar syntax before.

**My Goal**: I want to copy visible cells only from column that contains "MTD" in its first row. Visible cells I want to copy are in rows from 75 to 139 only.

```
'searching for column with "MTD" in it 
Dim NumCol As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Column = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To Column
    If Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value = "MTD" Then NumCol= i
Next i

'copying visible cells only from Column with MTD and only in rows from 75 to 139
 Dim MyRange As Range

 'Line below is the debugged line
 Set MyRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(75, NumCol), Cells(139, NumCol))
 MyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks ("xy.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
```

I also tried to use this, but 424 error appeared.

```
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(75,  NumCol), Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(139, NumCol))

'This time it debugged this row (error 424)
MyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("xy.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: I guess, 1004 error may be due to `NumCol`. if the Condition `If Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value = "MTD"` is never met in your for loop, then `NumCol` will be 0 and  in your next lines your code will be pointing to 0th Column and the error may occur.

Comment: Try to delete the `MyRange` and use `Columns(NumCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` instead. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Siva I tried to put MsgBox after the loop to see if that's the problem but it found the right one.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova 秀 but that will copy visible cells in whole column and I want to copy only in rows from 75 to 139.

Comment: @blau where does this code sits ? what is the Workbook (File) name ?

Comment: @Shai Rado its name is "AUTO_Download.xlsm" and it works with those files "xx.xlsx" and "xy.xlsx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line

```
Set MyRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(75, NumCol), Cells(139, NumCol))
MyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks ("xy.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
```

with

```
Set MyRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(75, NumCol), Cells(139, NumCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
MyRange.Copy Destination:=Workbooks ("xy.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
```

I think that should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If a Range object exists on a worksheet other than the ActiveWorksheet then it's cell references must also be qualified to that worksheet.

`Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1,1),Sheet1.Cells(1,10))`

This is not a fully qualified reference:

`Set MyRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(75, NumCol), Cells(139, NumCol))`

Passing the `Cells.Address` as parameters to shoud fix the problem.

`Set MyRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(75, NumCol).Address, Cells(139, NumCol).Address)`

```
Sub Example()
    Dim NumCol As Integer
    Dim Column As Integer

    With Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        NumCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("MTD", Rows(1), 0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Unable to locate MTD", vbCritical
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        'copying visible cells only from Column with MTD and only in rows from 75 to 139
        Dim MyRange As Range

        On Error Resume Next
        Set MyRange = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range(.Cells(75, NumCol), .Cells(139, NumCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "No cells were found", vbCritical
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then

            MyRange.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("xy.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```